# Get Text from Textbox in WIN PHONE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone

I have a problem with a solution built in VS Express for Windows 8 Phone.
MainPage.xaml is in designer mode and I added 3 Textboxes:

```
TextBox1, Textbox2, Textbox3
```

Now, I need to get data from these Textboxes to filename after click button.
Here is the button code:

```
Private Sub cam_GetFilename(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs)
```

```
Dim fileName As String = savedCounter & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("d") & ".jpg"
```

I'm looking for help on how to add Textbox1.value, Textbox2.value, Textbox3.value to code above like in example:

```
Dim fileName As String = savedCounter & "_" & Textbox1.value & "_" & Textbox2.value & "-" & Textbox3.value & "-" & DateTime.Now.ToString("d") & ".jpg"
```

Where Textbox1.value, Textbox2.value, Textbox3.value are from MainPage.xaml.

Comment: Use `.Text` **not .value**

Comment: When I did it I saw: Textbox1.Text, Textbox2.Text and Textbox3.Text underlined with error in description:
textbox1' is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: It that the correct name?...

Comment: @ Rishi Jasapara I added Public string definition and now I can get values from Textbox.
My second request is: how to change place for saved images. Images should to be saved to Camera roll to folder named from Textbox1.text.

Comment: this is for another question as it was not an issue in your original question. Please create a new question on your issue so other's can see it as well, don't add to the original. Thank You!

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice.